python: вычисление биномиального коэффициента (одностроковый код ограниченного размера)
решаю тут одну задачка:
дописать код
comb=lambda n,k:

для вычисления биномиального коэффициента, чтобы код не превышал 44 символа!
используя особенности разложения (1+x)^n в степенной ряд можно получить вот такую формулу:
comb=lambda n,k:((2**n+1)**n>>n*k)%2**n

что составляет 39 символов, но не корректно обрабатывает ситуацию n=k=0, C(0, 0)=1, а формула даёт 0
таким образом есть 5 символов, чтобы из n,k получить 1 для случая n=k=0 и 0 для все остальных
можно конечно сделать так:
+(n==k==0)

но это целых 10 байт :(
можно ли как то это все свести к 5 байтам или придётся основную формулу переделывать? :(

из +not(n|k) что-то можно сделать? Про 5 байт сомнительно

comb=__import__("math").comb - 28 байт всего )). Если же нужно с лямбдой, то comb=lambda n,k:__import__("math").comb(n,k) - ровно 44 байта. math.comb в стандартной библиотеке начиная с Python 3.8

+(n<1) . . . .

Только при +(n<1) ломаются случаи при n = 0, k > n - выдается 1, а не 0

@mrgervant, традиционно биномиальные коэффициенты определены в треугольнике 0 <= k <= n. Все числа за пределами треугольника или считаются неопределёнными или приравнены к нулю. Я предполагал первое.

@Pak Uula - какой вы хитрый :) все импорты конечно же запрещены :)

@Zhihar конечно хитрый) Программирование в первую очередь про переиспользование - если кто-то уже сделал, то надо этим пользоваться )))

@Zhihar если если ограничить область определения треугольниками 0 <= k <= n, то достаточно добавить к вашей формуле or 1. Тогда comb(0,0) станет равным 1.
